# Mutate string for testing with rspec and factory_girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot, rspec-rails

I'd like to test the validation of a model's attribute with rspec and factory_girl. The 'special' thing is, that one attribute (the name) isn't allowed to start with Numbers or special signs  like %,&,$, ...

For testing this it would be great to write only one example like

```rb
it "is invalid with name starting by special character" do
    ["1","$","%"].each do |i|
       name = i + "test"
       FactoryGirl.build(:tutu, name: name).should_not be_valid
    end
end
```

This work's for the first case but it won't return the result for the whole list. Is it possible to tell rspec not to stop on the error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do this instead:

```rb
["1","$","%"].each do |i|
  it "is invalid with name starting by '#{i}'" do
    FactoryGirl.build(:tutu, name: "#{i}test").should_not be_valid
  end
end
```

Comment: This shouldn't make any difference, should it?

Comment: This is only a more compact code - but doesn't change testing behaviour